# Apply with division operator in R

Tags: r, apply, division

How can I use the division operator inside an apply call in R?

I tried to use `apply` in R with a n x 2 matrix and with the division operator with the following syntax:

`apply(matrix,1,function)`

where I let `function` vary among these possibilities: `/`, `"/"`, `division`, `divide`, `rdivision`, `rdivide`.

None of them works.

I ended up with `A[,1]/A[,2]`.

Comment: `A[,1]/A[,2]` is the correct way

Comment: `A[,1] / A[,2]`does not divide the matrix by something, but the first column by the second.

Comment: @Nisba Please read [mcve] ... then **edit your question**! What is your expected result?

Comment: `m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,6,5,4), nrow = 2)
apply(m, 1, "/",2)` works for me ... but `m/2' also,as mentionned by @Geogery in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Georgery pointed out, `matrix / someVar`is the easiest way to do it. If you still want to use apply, you can use the following:

```
# choose the value with which every row value is divided
someVar = 2.5
# apply for each row, where row_val equals the values in your rows
apply(matrix, 1, function(row_val) row_val / someVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
`/`
```

But as R is conceptualized for using vectorized calculations.

```
matrix / someVar
```

is maybe the easier way to go.

Comment: @Georgery, if I do 'matrix1 = matrix(rnorm(3*4), 3, 4);    apply(matrix1, 1, `/`,2)' I get the answer I want but the matrix is also transposed. Why did the transposition happen? Am I doing something wrong?